# Will GATs allow HKTs for non-associated generic parameters?

Tags: rust, higher-kinded-types, generic-associated-types

When looking into Higher-kinded types (HKTs), Generic associated types (GATs) constantly pop up as "the solution". They allow you to express things like this (which I think is really cool):

```rust
trait Foo {
    type Bar<T>;

    fn process<T>(&mut self, ctx: Self::Bar<T>);
}
```

I'm really excited about GATs being close to landing, but from what I understand it only enables HKTs for traits that use associated types. Or is there a way to express something like this too? (And if not, is there a feature flag or working issue for it?)

```rust
trait Foo<for<T> Bar> {
    fn process<T>(&mut self, ctx: Self::Bar<T>);
}
```

Comment: As you'd expect, generic associated types only adds generics for associated types. It does not expand to generic parameters as a whole. I'm sure there have been proposals for more widely applicable higher-kinded types, and that would certainly be nice, but GATs are a way to get most of the functionality while staying relatively small in scope. ("relatively small" but has still been years in the making)

Comment: @kmdreko hmm, yeah, as expected. Some blogs herald GATs as “finally being able to use HKTs!” while that’s only partly true. It made me question if I just missed something here.

Comment: @StijnFrishert: (1) "finally being able to use HKTs" may be interpreted as "finally being able to use _some_ HKTs". (2) It is possible that GATs will allow your second example's functionality -- just in a more around-about way.